# Can't archive mail on one of my Exchange accounts

Tags: macos, mail.app, exchange

I have a few Exchange accounts set up in Mail that are working fine.  Deleting sends the mail to the Trash folder, archiving sends the mail to the Archive folder.  However, one of the accounts won't let me archive.  The mailbox has a folder under the "Archive" section on the sidebar, and I can manually drag messages to it, but when I click Archive I get the following:

**The message “[subject]” could not be moved to the mailbox “(null)”**

**The destination mailbox does not exist.**

I would assume this means that Mail can't find the appropriate folder to put the message in, but since the account has a folder under the Archive heading, I'm confused.

Any ideas?

Comment: Had the same problem on Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I went into Preferences > Accounts and deselected "Enable this account." Then, I quit Mail and restarted it. I went back into Preferences > Accounts and selected "Enable this account" and it all started working.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me with the same problem!

Comment: This worked for me just now (in 2023!), but with one modification: I had to fully delete my Exchange account in the "Internet Accounts" System Settings page, restart my Mac, and then add the account back in again.

Answer (score 2):

### Rename the Archive folder on Exchange

Seems some sort of bad situation manifested itself between Mail and the Exchange server. I had to Rename the folder named `Archive` on the server to `OldArchive`, then attempt to archive a message and allow Mail to recreate the `Archive` folder. Then I copied all the mail in `OldArchive` to the new `Archive`.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but I still faced this with macOS 10.15.4

None of the earlier tricks helped, but I found that by using another icon than the default 'archive' I can move the mails:

[image]

This is enough for me, for now. If you know how to really fix this for macOS in 2020, I'm all ears.